# MvvmLight with WindsorCastle: Conflicting Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light, castle-windsor, common-service-locator

I installed in my .NET project:

- MvvmLight v5.4.1.1
- Castle.Windsor v5.0.0
- CommonServiceLocator v2.0.2
- CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter.Unofficial v3.3.0

Then I initialize my container like this

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(container));
    container.Register(Component.For<MainViewModel>().ImplementedBy<MainViewModel>());
}
```

Which gives this error:

> The type 'ServiceLocatorImplBase' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.3.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Basically, MvvmLight v5.4.1.1 expects CommonServiceLocator v2.0.2, CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter.Unofficial expects CommonServiceLocator v1.3.0, and CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter expects CommonServiceLocator v1.0.0

One solution is to downgrade CommonServiceLocator to v1.3.0 and it works, but then MvvmLight also gets downgraded to v5.3.0

What's the right way to do this? How do I get MvvmLight and Windsor Castle working together?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer - just today got the same issue. And have a working solution.
Yes, the downgrade will work. And will block later MvvmLight updates or something else.
When your project will definitely require CommonServiceLocator version ^2.0.2, then you can replace not 'dead' WindsorServiceLocator adapter (for CommonServiceLocator v1) with another, that required for CommonServiceLocator v2. So...`CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider` expects `delegate IServiceLocator`. Then we will need an adapter that will wrap the existing `WindsorContainer container` into the `IServiceLocator` type and return it as a delegate.

Thanks to @zshewmaker (https://github.com/zshewmaker) there is his code for it. Please, check https://gist.github.com/zshewmaker/1074903 for the wrapper source.

Then your code could be the following:

```
//existing *.cs
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<MainViewModel>().ImplementedBy<MainViewModel>());
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new CastleServiceProvider(container));
}
```

where `CastleServiceProvider` implemented in this way:

```
//new CastleServiceProvider.cs
public class CastleServiceProvider : IServiceLocator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public CastleServiceProvider(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.Resolve(serviceType);
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type serviceType)
    {
        return container.Resolve(serviceType);
    }

    public object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        return container.Resolve(key, serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return (object[])container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
    }

    public TService GetInstance<TService>()
    {
        return container.Resolve<TService>();
    }

    public TService GetInstance<TService>(string key)
    {
        return container.Resolve<TService>(key);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TService> GetAllInstances<TService>()
    {
        return container.ResolveAll<TService>();
    }
}
```